# Get an array of all dates between 2 dates from every row in one array

Tags: php, arrays, date

I'm trying to get an array of all dates between the 2 dates which im getting out the database for each row. for example there is 3 rows with 2017-02-02 and 2017-02-03 and a row with 2017-02-18 and 2017-02-20 I would like to get an array with the output [2017-02-02, 2017-02-03, 2017-02-18, 2017-02-19, 2017-02-20]

So far I have a query which gets all of the dates and echo's the start and end date and a script to get an array with the dates between 2 dates.

How can I make it work so it's getting all the dates of every row into one array?

```
<?php
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM invoice_line WHERE car_car_id = $id");
    while ($auto = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?>
          <h2 class="title_car">
            <?php echo $auto['start_date'] . ' - ' . $auto['end_date'];?>
          </h2>
        <hr>
        <?php $dateRange = getDateRange($auto['start_date'], $auto['end_date']); ?>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php
    function getDateRange($startDate, $endDate, $format="Y-m-d")
{
    //Create output variable
    $datesArray = array();
    //Calculate number of days in the range
    $total_days = round(abs(strtotime($endDate) - strtotime($startDate)) / 86400, 0) + 1;
    //Populate array of weekdays and counts
    for($day=0; $day<$total_days; $day++)
    {
        $datesArray[] = date($format, strtotime("{$startDate} + {$day} days"));
    }
    //Return results array
    return $datesArray;
}

print_r($dateRange);
?>
```

Comment: Your function `getDateRange()` is working. So, why don't you call that function inside while loop?

Comment: @NanaPartykar Thanks for the reply edited the script calling the function inside the loop i was expecting to get an array with the dates of all rows of the database but im getting only the dates of the last row any idea what im doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry for late reply @marjin You did correct thing, just missed to print for each loop. Below is my answer. Please let me know, If I missed anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to foreach every array to print the dates.

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM invoice_line WHERE car_car_id = $id");
while ($auto = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {?>
  <h2 class="title_car">
    <?php echo $auto['start_date'] . ' - ' . $auto['end_date'];?>
  </h2>
  <hr>
  <?php 
  $date_text = "";
  $dateRange = getDateRange($auto['start_date'], $auto['end_date']);
  if(!empty($dateRange)){
    foreach($dateRange as $dateR){
      $date_text .= $dateR.", ";
    }
  }
  echo rtrim($date_text,", ")."<br>";
}?>
```

**Output:**

```
2011-05-03, 2011-05-04, 2011-05-05, 2011-05-06, 2011-05-07, 2011-05-08

2011-05-20, 2011-05-21, 2011-05-22, 2011-05-23

.

.
.
```

Comment: Thanks i only need to get them in 1 array now but i think i will get it

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DatePeriod](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php) class.

Your code would something like this:

```
<?php
$rows = [
    [ new DateTime(), (new DateTime())->modify('+3 days') ],
    [ (new DateTime())->modify('+20 days'), (new DateTime())->modify('+30 days') ],
];

$dates = [];

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $dateRange = new DatePeriod($row[0], new DateInterval('P1D'), $row[1]);

    foreach ($dateRange as $date) {
        $dates[] = $date;
    }
}

var_dump($dates);
```